# If $\frac{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}-1}{(a_{1}-1)(a_{2}-1)(a_{3}-1)\cdots(a_{n}-1)}\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$, how to find $a_{i}$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> Let $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ is positive integer, and such $1<a_{1}<a_{2}<\cdots<a_{n}$ and 
>   $$\dfrac{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}-1}{(a_{1}-1)(a_{2}-1)(a_{3}-1)\cdots(a_{n}-1)}\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$$
>   find the $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$?

I know these particular cases:

**When $n=3$**

> If $1<a_{1}<a_{2}<a_{3}$,and 
>   $$\dfrac{a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}-1}{(a_{1}-1)(a_{2}-1)(a_{3}-1)}\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$$
>   then we have 
>   $(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})=(2,4,8)$ or $(3,5,15)$, and this full solution can see
>   [link solution](http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=ax2Dh6Jyiwy0daOVTtmD6QGnhfFX2SxSyEUiUT7YSSe5ccy5OB3AgqeSoKuZeUfoSRKP9s2eeGpgkkXykC-xt874TY4p08C17CRHydNzDmu)

**and when $n=4$,**

> This is 1996 Monthly Problem:
>   Find all sets of distinct integers $1 < a < b < c < d$, such
>   $$\dfrac{abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$$
>   then we have  $(a,b,c,d)=(2,4,10,80)$ or $(3,5,17,255)$, and the full solution can be found here: http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM10523.pdf

What about the general case?

Thank you

Comment: I upvoted the question because it is interesting. But I see a problem. Let's assume we can solve it. How would we even *represent* the general solution in terms of $n$? I think if someone can address this, the question might see progress.

Comment: Yes,I guess maybe when $n=3,4$have exsit it,and when $n\ge 5$,we can't find $a_{i}$ such $\dfrac{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}-1}{(a_{1}-1)(a_{2}-1)\cdots(a_{n}-1)}\in N$,maybe my guess is wrong

Comment: Does something go wrong for general $n$ if you try to emulate the proof in the pdf you linked to (for $n=4$)?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_k=a_k-1$. Then $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ are positive integers such that $0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n$. Further we have $x_1 \geq 1$ and $x_m \geq x_{m-1}+1$. Our function

$$R(\mathbf{x}) = \frac {\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x_k+1)-1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}x_k}, \quad R \in \mathbb{N}^+$$

To cut the long story short here are the solutions:

Case $n=1$: $R( \mathbf{x})=1$. Solutions: $x_1=1,2,\dots$

Case $n=2$: No Solutions

Case $n=3$: 2 Solutions $(x,y,z,R)=(2,4,14,2)$ or $(1,3,7,3)$

Case $n=4$: 2 Solutions $(w,x,y,z,R)=(2,4,16,254,2)$ and $(1,3,9,79,3)$

Case $n=5$: 2 Solutions: $(v,w,x,y,z,R)=(2,4,16,256,65534,2)$ and $(1,3,9,81,6559,3)$

Can you spot the pattern? R is always 2 or 3. For the even solution you start with $2$, then square it, then square that and so on except at the end you square and subtract $2$. Similarly for the odd case starting at 1 and using powers of $3$. Easily generalizable. But these numbers are enormous: the even solution for n=8 is

$2$,

$4$,

$16$,

$256$,

$65536$,

$4294967296$,

$18446744073709551616$,

$340282366920938463463374607431768211456$,

$115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639934$.

I have to get some sleep now and will post the proof tomorrow.

Comment: When $n=5$, there are already more solutions than the ones you listed. Take for example $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)=(2, 4, 10, 112, 290)$. In your notation, that is $(v, w, x, y, z, R)=(1, 3, 9, 111, 289, 3)$.

Comment: Hm, Interesting...

Comment: Now that you mention it, one more even sol is $(2,4,16,284,2506,2)$ and two more odd ones: $(1,3,9,91,669,3)$ and $(1,3,9,99,421,3)$. It would be nice if they where unique but no such luck!